# Python/Pandas Timedelta with only 1 digit on Hours?

Tags: python, pandas, format, timedelta

I have a Pandas Dataframe (data) with a column "Duration" that represents the time duration in hours, minutes, seconds with a format like: "1:10:27"

**How to convert the column to Pandas Timedelta?**
I tried:

```
data['Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['Duration'])
```

But it says:
"ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format before"

I suspect this happens because the format has only 1 digit for hours.
The rows show "1:30:27" instead of "01:30:27". Or "0:57:23" instead of "00:57:23"

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: There is no error on my side. I tried `['0:57:23', '1:07:14']`

Comment: I figured out my problem. Duration times less than 10 minutes are shown with milliseconds like this: 09:14.5
So, first I need to find a way to strip the milliseconds and then convert to timedelta

Answer (score 0):

Using inputs that you described I'm guessing it's something like the following, but it's working fine for me. If you have a specific input that's different, feel free to post it.

```
import pandas as pd
time = "1:30:27"
print(pd.to_timedelta(time))
```

Output:

```
0 days 01:30:27
```

Comment: I figured out my problem. Duration times less than 10 minutes are shown with milliseconds like this: 08:42.2
So, first I need to find a way to strip the milliseconds and then convert to timedelta